# System of ODE with piecewise functionals

Tags: differential-equations, piecewise

I am trying to solve a system of ODE. I am new to Mathematica
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
What I am trying to get is the plot labelled 1 & 2.

```
τ = 1;
A = 0.98;
equa = {y1'[t] == (
     y0 - y1[t])/τ + α1[t]*(y1[t] - y2[t])/τ,
   y2'[t] == (
     y1[t] - y2[t])/τ + α2[t]*
      y2[t]/τ - α1[t]*(y1[t] - y2[t])/τ,
   y0 == 1, y1[0] == 0, y2[0] == 0};
```

The piecewise functions are alpha1 and alpha2. There are also piecewise functions within alpha1 and alpha2. I only tried simulating up to n=2.

```
d1[t_] := 
  Piecewise[{{(y1[t])^0.5, y1[t] < 0.5}, {(1 - y1[t])^0.5, 
     y1[t] > 0.5}}];
d2[t_] := 
  Piecewise[{{(y2[t])^0.5, y2[t] < 0.5}, {(1 - y2[t])^0.5, 
     y2[t] > 0.5}}];
α1[t_] := 
  Piecewise[{{0, d1[t] = 0}, {(A* d1[t])/(d1[t] + d2[t]), 
     d1[t] != 0}}];
α2[t_] := Piecewise[{{0, d2[t] = 0}, {A, d2[t] != 0}}];
```

I use NDSolve to solve the system of ODE

```
sol = NDSolve[equa,{y1,y2},{t,0,10}];
Plot[Evaluate[{y1[t], y2[t]} /. s], {t, 0, 10}, 
 PlotLabel -> "Layer Coverage Dynamics", AxesLabel -> {t, Coverage}, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

This returns a plot, however, it is not the plot that I am expecting. It seems to me that the Piecewise portion in the system of ODE is not taken into account during NDSolve. I am new to this so please bear with me.

Update: So I edited my code according to the comments

```
τ = 1;
A = 0.98;
d1[t_] := 
  Piecewise[{{(y1[t])^0.5, y1[t] < 0.5}, {(1 - y1[t])^0.5, 
     y1[t] > 0.5}}];
d2[t_] := 
  Piecewise[{{(y2[t])^0.5, y2[t] < 0.5}, {(1 - y2[t])^0.5, 
     y2[t] > 0.5}}];
α1[t_] := 
  Piecewise[{{0, d1[t] == 0}, {(A* d1[t])/(d1[t] + d2[t]), 
     d1[t] != 0}}];
α2[t_] := Piecewise[{{0, d2[t] == 0}, {A, d2[t] != 0}}];
equa = {y1'[t] == (
     y0 - y1[t])/τ + α1[t]*(y1[t] - y2[t])/τ,
   y2'[t] == (
     y1[t] - y2[t])/τ + α2[t]*
      y2[t]/τ - α1[t]*(y1[t] - y2[t])/τ,
   y0 == 1, y1[0] == 0, y2[0] == 0};
s = NDSolve[equa, {y1, y2}, {t, 0, 10}];
Plot[Evaluate[{y1[t], y2[t]} /. s], {t, 0, 10}, 
 PlotLabel -> "Layer Coverage Dynamics", AxesLabel -> {t, Coverage}, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

Now, it returns 2 NDSolve errors:
[image: NDSolve::nrnum1]

[image]

Does anyone have any idea how to resolve these issues? Any help would be appreciated. :)

Comment: I guess "/.s" should read "/.sol" And what plot are you expecting?

Comment: @Daniel Huber Thank you for your reply. what I am expecting can be found here: [link](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/a-The-surface-coverage-of-growing-layers-for-the-quasi-layer-by-layer-growth-mode-as-a_fig2_345483835) However, the y2[t] graph in my code shows a very steep initial transient and what I am expecting to see would be a gentler slope

Comment: `Piecewise[{{0, d2[t] = 0}, {A, d2[t] != 0}}]` should be `Piecewise[{{0, d2[t] == 0}, {A, d2[t] != 0}}]` and similarly elsewhere.  Do not confuse `Set` with `Equal`.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Thank you for the tip :)

Comment: @Chris Your model is not same as in a paper linked. Why do you expect to get same picture as in Figure 1?

Comment: @AlexTrounev Hi, I apologise for the misinformation. [link](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Birth-death-models-of-epitaxy.-I.-Diffraction-from-Cohen-Petrich/f3b2c1c614fa49138b15a26c65e3c82d24219bad) This paper is more accurate in describing what I am trying to do. The figure can be found in Figure 11.

Comment: @Chris I have no access to this paper. Could you upload equations and Figure 11?

Comment: @AlexTrounev I have edited the question to include the equations and the plot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use name for function $\theta_i=y[i]$,then code for $i=0,1,...,15$ can be written as follows

```
tau = 1;
A = .98; nn = 15; Y = Table[y[i][t], {i, -1, nn + 1}]; Y1 = 
 Table[y[i]'[t], {i, -1, nn + 1}];
y[-1][t_] := 1; 
y[nn + 1][t_] := 0; ic = 
 Join[{y[0][0] == 10^-10}, Table[y[i][0] == 10^-10, {i, nn}]]; var = 
 Table[y[i], {i, 0, nn}];
d[x_] := Piecewise[{{0, x <= 0}, {Sqrt[Abs[x]], 
     x <= 1/2}, {Sqrt[Abs[1 - x]], x > 1/2}, {0, x >= 1}}];
alpha[x_, z_] := 
  If[d[x] == 0, 0, If[d[z] == 0, 0, (A*d[x])/(d[x] + d[z])]];
eq = Table[
   Y1[[n]] == (Y[[n - 1]] - Y[[n]])/tau + 
     alpha[Y[[n]], Y[[n + 1]]]/tau (Y[[n]] - Y[[n + 1]]) - 
     alpha[Y[[n - 1]], Y[[n]]]/tau (Y[[n - 1]] - Y[[n]]), {n, 2, 
    nn + 2}];

soln = NDSolve[Join[eq, ic], var, {t, 0, 10}];
```

Visualization

```
Plot[Evaluate[Drop[Drop[Y, 1], -1] /. soln[[1]]], {t, 0, 10}, 
 PlotLabel -> "Layer Coverage Dynamics", AxesLabel -> {t, Coverage}, 
 PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotLegends -> Table[Subscript[\[Theta], i], {i, 0, 10}]]
```

[image: Figure 1]

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I tried your code on my notebook but I was not able to get the same plot. I got an error NDSolve::ndsz instead. Do you have any packages loaded initially? I really appreciate your help

Comment: @Chris Sorry, code has been updated. Try again.